# Is there an easy way reverse a template render?

Tags: django, django-templates

I can do this to render a template.

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
>>> c = Context({"my_name": "Adrian"})
>>> t.render(c)
u'My name is Adrian.'
```

Now I would like to take the rendered template, and from that, get the context. Something like:

```
>>> t.reverse_render('My name is Adrian.')
{"my_name": "Adrian"}
```

Is this even a good idea?

UPDATE: The reason I want to do this is because I'm receiving XML with a well-defined structure, and I think extracting the data this way would be much easier than manually parsing the XML.

I'm using an XML template to send the response and that got me wondering if I could handle the request in a similar, but reverse, fashion.

Comment: Could you may be clarify your use case, i.e. why do you need this?

Comment: I updated the question with my reasoning.

Comment: I see, my personal opinion - you need to parse XML, or switch to JSON somehow, then you can easily unserialize it to dict in python.

Comment: Huh. Interesting idea. Given that Django templates can contain tags, which can (kind of, I think) do anything that Python code can, implementing this fully might be a bit tricky. If it was just limited to variable names, some sort of diff... thingy might be capable of figuring it out.

Comment: Good point about the tags, but I can guarantee the template will have no tags, just variables and a for loop. It seems like it should be doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very similar way to do it without Django templates that would have worked well for me at the time:

```
import re

tmpl = 'My name is (?P<name>.*).\nI like to ride my (?P<transport>.*).'
msg = 'My name is Adrian.\nI like to ride my bicycle.'
print(re.compile(tmpl).match(msg).groupdict())
```

Outputs:

```
{'name': 'Adrian', 'transport': 'bicycle'}
```

The XML regular expression template could still be kept in an XML file and read in at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not a Django feature. So, no, there is no way in Django. If you have the template, you will have to create a way of parsing the html/xml, and compare it with the template in order to associate each change to each {{context_label}}.

This seems like an interesting problem, but I don't see how its solution can be useful in a standard web-app (thus I see no reason why Django would have this feature in the first place).